# Converting ssd_mobilenet to tensorflow lite throws, ConverterError: TOCO failed. See console for info

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to convert ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco available from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md#coco-trained-models to TFLite. But it is throwing following error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConverterError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-c2bf9c96c1d4> in <module>()
----> 1 lite_model = converter.convert()
      2 
      3 open( folder_name + '.tflite', 'wb' ).write( lite_model )

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/convert.py in toco_convert_protos(model_flags_str, toco_flags_str, input_data_str)
    170       stderr = _try_convert_to_unicode(stderr)
    171       raise ConverterError(
--> 172           "TOCO failed. See console for info.\n%s\n%s\n" % (stdout, stderr))
    173   finally:
    174     # Must manually cleanup files.

ConverterError: TOCO failed. See console for info.
2019-08-24 04:48:54.444064: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-08-24 04:48:54.475768: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-08-24 04:48:54.475895: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.475960: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-08-24 04:48:54.475987: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.476003: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-08-24 04:48:54.476017: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.476030: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-08-24 04:48:54.476043: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-08-24 04:48:54.476061: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-08-24 04:48:54.476073: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-08-24 04:48:54.476086: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-08-24 04:48:54.476101: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-08-24 04:48:54.476113: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-08-24 04:48:54.476125: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-08-24 04:48:54.476148: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-08-24 04:48:54.476161: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-08-24 04:48:54.476183: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayScatterV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.476202: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: LoopCond
2019-08-24 04:48:54.476228: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-08-24 04:48:54.476258: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Exit
2019-08-24 04:48:54.476277: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Exit
2019-08-24 04:48:54.476300: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArraySizeV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.476315: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArraySizeV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.476342: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayReadV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.476385: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayWriteV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.476406: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayGatherV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.476423: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayGatherV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.476504: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayWriteV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477386: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477421: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477449: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477463: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477477: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477493: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477507: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477519: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477532: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477544: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477558: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477570: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477583: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477595: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477608: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477620: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477632: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477651: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477665: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477677: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477689: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477700: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayScatterV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477728: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477741: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477753: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayScatterV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477766: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477779: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477806: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477834: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477861: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477873: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477887: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477898: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477919: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477934: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477946: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477958: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-08-24 04:48:54.477971: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-08-24 04:48:54.478010: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2019-08-24 04:48:54.478040: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayScatterV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.478072: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-08-24 04:48:54.478086: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-08-24 04:48:54.478106: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: LoopCond
2019-08-24 04:48:54.478120: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-08-24 04:48:54.478147: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Exit
2019-08-24 04:48:54.478162: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Exit
2019-08-24 04:48:54.478179: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Exit
2019-08-24 04:48:54.478194: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Exit
2019-08-24 04:48:54.478214: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArraySizeV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.478227: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArraySizeV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.478239: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArraySizeV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.478251: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArraySizeV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.478284: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayReadV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.478299: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayReadV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.478312: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayReadV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.480962: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayScatterV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.481010: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayGatherV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.481029: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayGatherV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.481045: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayGatherV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.481059: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayGatherV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.481077: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Enter
2019-08-24 04:48:54.481099: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayReadV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.485710: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.485745: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.485762: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.485776: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.485789: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.485818: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.485831: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.485855: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.485879: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.485894: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.485914: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.485930: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.485949: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.485962: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.485975: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.485988: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486001: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486014: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486027: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486041: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486054: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486067: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486080: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486108: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486122: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486135: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486148: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486162: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486175: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486188: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486220: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486236: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486249: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486270: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486296: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486310: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486323: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486353: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486368: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486382: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486396: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486409: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486436: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486451: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486464: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486477: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486490: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486503: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486517: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486530: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486543: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486556: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486569: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486583: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486596: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486609: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486622: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486636: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486659: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486673: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486686: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486700: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486713: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486726: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486739: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486752: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486765: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486779: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486800: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486814: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486830: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486844: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486857: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486871: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486884: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486898: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486931: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486946: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486959: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486973: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.486986: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.487000: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.487013: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.487035: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.487050: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.487063: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.487077: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.487090: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.487103: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.487117: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: NonMaxSuppressionV2
2019-08-24 04:48:54.487655: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: Size
2019-08-24 04:48:54.487742: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayWriteV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.488021: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayWriteV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.488044: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayWriteV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.488058: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: TensorArrayWriteV3
2019-08-24 04:48:54.815195: I tensorflow/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] Before Removing unused ops: 4139 operators, 6859 arrays (0 quantized)
2019-08-24 04:48:55.234858: I tensorflow/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] After Removing unused ops pass 1: 4116 operators, 6815 arrays (0 quantized)
2019-08-24 04:48:55.796827: I tensorflow/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] Before general graph transformations: 4116 operators, 6815 arrays (0 quantized)
2019-08-24 04:48:56.183189: F tensorflow/lite/toco/graph_transformations/resolve_tensorflow_switch.cc:98] Check failed: other_op->type == OperatorType::kMerge Found StridedSlice as non-selected output from Switch, but only Merge supported.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Colab notebook to reproduce the error : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1FcalJTa1IRuTsPOJ9f3oiUnIkhvj0Q_Y

Colab runtime : GPU

Is this due to any unsupported layers or am I making any mistakes? TIA.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I was using official frozen_inference_graph.pb. But TFLite is expecting SSDs exported using this script.https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/export_tflite_ssd_graph.py. The input_array and output_array is different here. This can be found on the comments provided in the export script.